# Dynamic List<int> in c# to store integers based on an index supplied by other code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

this might seem stupid and there might be better ways to achieving what I need but I was asked to specifically use this way to achieve it.
anyway, so to make it clear I have the following situation:
I'm writing a method that will return a list of integers, also I have a db table of students and another db table with courses for the students, what I want to do is to get how many times a students Id appears in the courses table and store it in a "Total Courses Enrolled In" field then do it for all the students, and since the student numbers change over time(right now 8 are present), so I need a list to do the following:
take the student's Id as an index and store the total number of courses in that index so when I access the value of that index it will return the total courses for that student.

I'm new at working with lists and the following was my code, please be gentle as it may be a very stupid coding:

```
public List<int> totalcourses()
    {
        int id = 0;
        List<int> TotalCoursesPerStudent = new List<int>();
        foreach (Student std in db.Students)
        {
            id = std.Id;
            TotalCoursesPerStudent[id] = 0;

            foreach (StdCourse stdcourse in db.StdCourses)
            {
                if (stdcourse.StdId == id)
                {
                    TotalCoursesPerStudent[id] += 1;
                }
            }
        }
        return TotalCoursesPerStudent;
    }
```

**Update:**

so I forgot to say that I want to use this number of total courses and implement it in the following code to add the ability to sort students based on their total courses, following is the sorting code inside the index action method:

```
public ActionResult Index(string SearchTerm, string sortBy, int? page)
    {
        ViewBag.SortByName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortBy) ? "Name desc" : "";
        ViewBag.SortByTotalMarks = sortBy == "TotalMarks" ? "TotalMarks desc" : "TotalMarks";
        ViewBag.SortByTC = sortBy == "TotalCourses" ? "Total Courses desc" : "Total Courses";



        var students = db.Students.AsQueryable();

        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchTerm))
        {
            students = db.Students;
        }
        else
        {
            students = db.Students.Where(x => x.FirstName.StartsWith(SearchTerm) || 
            x.LastName.StartsWith(SearchTerm));
        }

        switch(sortBy)
        {
            case "Name desc":
                students = db.Students.OrderByDescending(x => x.FirstName);
                break;

            case "TotalMarks desc":
                students = db.Students.OrderByDescending(x => x.TotalMarks);
                break;
            case "TotalMarks":
                students = db.Students.OrderBy(x => x.TotalMarks);
                break;
            case "Total Courses desc":
                **// here to sort desc based on total courses.**
                break;
            case "Total Courses":
                **// here to sort asc based on total courses.**
                break;
            default:
                students = db.Students.OrderBy(x => x.FirstName);
                break;
        }

        return View(students.ToPagedList(page ?? 1,3));
    }
```

Comment: You should probably make use of a `Dictionary<int, int>` and a LINQ `GroupJoin` that returns the count of courses for every student.

Comment: `db.StdCourses.GroupBy(c=>c.StdId).ToDictionary(g=>g.Key, g=>g.Count())`

Comment: If you have set up your data base correctly with navigation properties, then this is just a simple `.GroupBy()` clause - `db.StdCourses.GroupBy(x => x.StdId).Select(y => new { SudentId = y.Key, TotalCourses = y.Count() });`

Comment: sorry I forget to mention I need to sort the students in the view based on their total courses, I'll append the code used to sort them that I already have.

Comment: the thing is the field total courses is not present in the database unlike the total marks field but is implemented by the view to appear beside each student with the value.
and my issue is that I'm not to change the settings of the db like add new tables or fields for existing tables.

Comment: You can do that with linq as well :) But since you querying `Students`, then just use `.Include(x => x.Courses)` or whatever your collection property is named and then you can just sort by its `.Count()`

Comment: thanks for the help, it seems all I needed to do was db.Students.OrderBy(x => x.StdCourses.Count())